# How to execute tshark in python for every file in a folder

Tags: python, tshark

I have About 100 `.pcap` files which i want to analyze. I would like to use tshark for this. My idea is to use a python script to automate this task. It has to run the following command for every .pcap file in my Folder:

```
tshark -r filename1.pcap -q -z io,stat,1 >> outfile1.txt
```

So for every `filename.pcap` I want to have an `outfile.txt`.

Here is my Approach:

```
import os
inputdir = "C:/testfolder"
command = "tshark -r *.pcap -q -z io,stat,1 >> outfile.txt"
for pcapFilename in os.listdir(inputdir):
       if not pcapFilename.endswith(".pcap"):
          continue
       os.system(command)
```

I know this does not work. But at the moment i am a bit stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using Python if the only thing you want is run an external command? This would make more sense as a shell script or batch script. (I'll give you that Windows batch script sucks.)

```py
import os
import subprocess

inputdir = "C:/testfolder"
with open("outfile.txt","w") as outfile:
    for pcapFilename in os.listdir(inputdir):
         if not pcapFilename.endswith(".pcap"):
            continue
         subprocess.run(["tshark", "-r",
             os.path.join(inputdir, pcapFilename),
             "-q", "-z", "io,stat,1"],
            stdout=outfile, check=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

solved Problem by myself.

```
`@echo off 
    set cap_files="*.pcap" 
    set cap_folder="c:\testfolder\" 
    set tshark_cmd="c:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark" 
    echo. > %outfile% 
    for /r %cap_folder% %%f in (%cap_files%) do ( 
    echo Processing File: %%f %tshark_cmd% -r %%f -q -z io,stat,1 >> %%f.txt ) 
    echo.`
```

Thanks for your help. Yes python does not make so much sense here but I like to practice coding.